# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined, function returning Null

Tags: javascript, processing.js

This is an object method from a program using Processing,js. It iterates through all the PVector objects stored in the forces array within the object, adding them up, and returning the sum as another PVector object.

After debugging,I have found that it is the cause for the error, 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined' and I just don't understand the problem, or what the error even means. Any help is appreciated.

```
Body.prototype.resForce = function() {
    var resForce = new PVector(0, 0);
    for (var i=0; i<this.forces.length; i++) {
        resForce.set = resForce.add(this.forces[i]);
    }
return resForce;
};
```

EDIT:

Here's the [full code](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/2d-physics-lab/4849221508005888) so it makes a bit more sense..

Comment: On the right hand side, it should show the line number of the offending error. Please check to make sure that this error occurs within this code block, or post the other javascript attached to this project so we can look into this further.

Comment: It's a guess, but the processing.js docs don't have a usage of "set" on a PVector like that.
If it's just adding up vectors to produce a delta, I think the body of the loop should just be resForce.add() without the assignment.
Additionally, probably the resForce.add call is trying to access the property "x" of the this.forces[i] but this.forces[i] doesn't have an x, so you probably have something in the array that isn't a PVector.

Comment: Actually, looking at it a bit more closely, I think you need to share the code that declares and populates this.forces. It's relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the responses @Mic and Danbopes. Here's the full code:(https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/2d-physics-lab/4849221508005888). A lot of things are constantly being changed/commentted out which was why I didn't want to share it

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have resolved this issue after playing around quite a bit which the code. What I gather from debugging is that somewhere along the line, the .forces variable of every Body object was turn from being an Array, into being undefined, causing the .resForce() method to fail to iterate through all the forces, and returning an undefined object. The method which I thought was the problem was left untouched. Thanks for all the help offered anyways. :)